# Change keyboard GO button to Done for Phonegap application for iPad

Tags: ipad, cordova

I have worked on iOS native applications, and now started working on Phonegap applications.
I have HTML pages on which I have input tags on it. Whenever I tap on input tags, iOS default keyboard appears and shows G0 button. I want to change that Go button and I want to show Done button.

Is there any way in Phonegap to do such type of functionality?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ionic has an open bug regarding this issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/54